# Embedding of $F(4)$ in $OSp(8|4)$?

Tags: string-theory, lie-algebra, superconformality, superalgebra

Is the superconformal algebra in five dimensions, $F(4)$, a subalgebra of the (maximal) six-dimensional superconformal algebra $OSp(8|4)$?

Answer (score 3):

So I asked [Jeff Harvey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_A._Harvey) about this, and this is what he told me.

"I suppose one could figure it out by first looking at whether there is an embedding of the
bosonic subalgebra and if that works going on to look at the fermionic generators and checking
if one can piece the two parts of the embedding together."

Answer (score 3):

The bosonic subalgebra of $F(4)$ is $SO(5,2)\times SU(2)$. This certainly can be embedded into the bosonic subalgebra of $OSp(8|4)$ which is $SO(6,2)\times SO(5)$. The tricky bit is indeed to figure out the fermionic generators.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the answer to the question is "no", as shown in Appendix C.4.1 of this paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1484

Comment: Do you not want to ask the mods to merge your account for you? http://physics.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1484